# I am trying to enlarge a map using the map function (hurricane tracks)

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to make my map appear larger because even if I go to save it and change the size the map is still too small. I am trying to map hurricane tracks through a point in florida.

[image]

```
map("world", ylim = c(12, 60), xlim = c(-90, -50))                                                 
for (i in 35:1) {                                                                                  
   clr = gray((i - 1)/Ns)                                                                            
   Lo = ngu$tracks[[i]]$lon                                                                          
   La = ngu$tracks[[i]]$lat                                                                         
   n = length(Lo)                                                                                  
   lines(Lo, La, lwd = 2, col = clr)                                                                  
   arrows(Lo[n - 1], La[n - 1], Lo[n], La[n], lwd = 2, length = 0.1, col = clr)                      
}
```

Comment: I cant recreate this. It looks like you may have some of your graphical parameters set from previous figures. Try resetting by running `dev.off()` and then map again. Does the problem still persist after trying that?